# Hiding only text but not iframe in a DIV

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty hiding text from a DIV whilst still allowing the iframe within the div to appear. Here is sample code:

```
<div class="whatever">
    <iframe src="http://something"></iframe>
    Here is some text with <a href="#">links</a> and <strong>bold text</strong>
</div>
```

I need only the `<iframe>` to appear. Is this easily achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see this example: http://jsbin.com/ewozak/1/edit

```
.whatever {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

the content into the iframe is not influenced by the font-size set on its parent

Comment: thanks! i thought of that and came back here to fill in my own answer - but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xWmfK/

Create a `hidden` class and add `display:none` to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="whatever">
    <iframe src="http://something"></iframe>
    <p class="hidden">
    Here is some text with <a href="#">links</a> and <strong>bold text</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**
    .hidden {display:none}

Comment: i'm limited to wrap the text in the div into a p or span tag :(, however, font-size:0px worked :)